# Error while creating CustomSOAPProvider in ADF Mobile

Tags: soap, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, soapheader

I want to add the security headers to the SOAP request from the ADF mobile application to the webservice.

But when I am trying to extend the oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.provider.soap.SOAPProvider class in my CustomSOAPProvider class, it says "Illegal Internal package import. Please use public api".

I have changed the audit rules as Tools - Preferences - Audit - Profiles - Audit Rules - Application Development Framework - ADF Common - ADF java audit rules - "Illegal Internal package import. Please use public api" severity and style to "Warning". But still it is not working.

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0 version.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
<wsse:Username>myuser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">3xp9MFe3E1BDAPjr8ipA8A==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2013-02-13T08:58:50.649Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

This is my SOAP security header.

Please help...